# Irregular movements of the left and right trackballs/mice in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently I am dealing with the irregular movements ([video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yQv8jFsvRI3_RRoxaUXqOXqy-Wic96Sv/view?usp=sharing)) of the left and right trackballs/mice which are based on the x and y axis values from corresponding trackballs/mice.

These are the methods that are responsible for the movements

```
public void Update()
    {
            while (inputQueue.TryDequeue(out var val))
        {
        if (val.Header.Type == RawInputType.Mouse && val.Header.Device.ToInt32() == leftTrackballDeviceID)
        {
            float mouseX = val.Data.Mouse.LastX;
            float mouseY = -val.Data.Mouse.LastY;
            UpdateCursorPosition(leftCursor, mouseX, mouseY);
            }
        else if (val.Header.Type == RawInputType.Mouse && val.Header.Device.ToInt32() == rightTrackballDeviceID)
            {
            float mouseX = val.Data.Mouse.LastX;
            float mouseY = -val.Data.Mouse.LastY;
            UpdateCursorPosition(rightCursor, mouseX, mouseY);
            }
        }

    }


private void UpdateCursorPosition(GameObject cursor, float x, float y)
    {
        Vector3 currentPosition = cursor.transform.position;
        currentPosition.x += x * cursorSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        currentPosition.y -= y * cursorSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        cursor.transform.position = currentPosition;
    }
```

Currently, I am don't know what is happeing with my code.
I want the cursors (red moving circles in the video) to just move over the keyboard buttons (such that it will always intersect a button when moving).I am working on a 3D VR project in Unity.Please help me to figure out the problem.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the angles how things are laid out in the video, you either want to be changing the z position instead of y position, or doing the changes within local space of the keyboard buttons rather than world space.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I want to change the z position instead of the y position. For example, the current position of the right red ball is on button "K".  If I want to go to button "P", do I need to change to Z direction? I am not getting how I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem in the `UpdateCursorPosition` method and it is caused by not smoothing the raw input. The mouse raw values, despite its `float`, are actually discrete, so it goes say from 128.0 to 129.0 without intermediate, and in some frames your X delta could be much larger than Y or vice versa, which then are mutiplied and applied to the cursor without normalization.

I don't know why you're using raw input, but my advice, besides vector normalization and multiplication by speed after, would be to use Unity's new Input System package. That thing alone would remove a whole layer of headache in your endeavour.